# Display data dynamically in a popup control

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, popup, devexpress

I have a devexpress popup control which displays a tree view, what I would like to happen is:

1: User clicks on a row

2: Clicked Row's UserLogin is sent to controller via JQuery and Popup appears

3: Controller gets rights details and sends them to tree view

4: Popup Updates to show tree view <==== THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS

Is there a way via JQuery/Ajax to update the popup so it shows the new data? also should the `UserRightsTreeListPartial` controller update to itself or to the popup? or maybe even in the Popup partial should I use `@Html.RenderAction`?

Thanks for your help and let me know if you need anything else.

**_UserTreePopupControl**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="vertComponentContainer">
        @Html.DevExpress().PopupControl(settings =>
   {
       settings.Name = "UserTreePopupControl";
       settings.PopupElementID = "UserGridView_DXDataRow0";
       settings.Height = 400;
       settings.Width = 400;
       settings.AllowResize = true;
       settings.ShowHeader = true;
       settings.ShowOnPageLoad = false;
       settings.AllowDragging = true;
       settings.DragElement = DragElement.Header;
       settings.CloseAction = CloseAction.OuterMouseClick;
       settings.ShowCloseButton = false;
       settings.CloseOnEscape = true;
       settings.Modal = false;
       settings.HeaderText = "Rights List";
       settings.ScrollBars = System.Web.UI.WebControls.ScrollBars.Vertical;
       settings.EnableHotTrack = true;


       settings.SetContent(() =>
       {
           Html.RenderAction("UserRightsTreeListPartial"); <===== THIS CALLS TREE LIST INTO POPUP
       });
   }).GetHtml()
    </div>

}
```

**_UserRightsTreeListPartial**

```
{
    var treeList = Html.DevExpress().TreeList(settings => {
        settings.Name = "UserRightsTreeList";
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "UserRightsTreeListPartial" };
        settings.SettingsBehavior.AutoExpandAllNodes = true;
        settings.Images.CollapsedButton.Width = 0;
        settings.Images.CollapsedButton.Height = 0;
        settings.Images.ExpandedButton.Width = 0;
        settings.Images.ExpandedButton.Height = 0;

        settings.KeyFieldName = "Item1";
        settings.ParentFieldName = "Item2";
        //settings.SettingsSelection.Recursive = true;


        settings.Columns.Add(
            column =>
            {
                column.FieldName = "Item1";
                column.Visible = false;
                column.ReadOnly = true;
            }
        );
        settings.Columns.Add(
    column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "Item2";
        column.SortIndex = 0;
        column.SortOrder = DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Ascending;
        column.Visible = false;
        column.ReadOnly = true;
    }
);
        settings.Columns.Add(
    column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "Item3";
        column.Name = "Rights";
        column.ReadOnly = true;

    }
);

        settings.SettingsPager.Visible = true;
        settings.SettingsPager.Mode = TreeListPagerMode.ShowAllNodes;
        settings.SettingsSelection.Enabled = false;
    });
}
@treeList.Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

**Home Controller**

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult UserRightsTreeListPartial(string userLogin)
    {


        if (userLogin != null)
        {
            var userlogins = userLogin;
            Manager manager = new Manager();
            var userRightsDetails = manager.GetUserRightsData(userlogins);
            ViewData["UserLogin"] = userlogins;
            var rights = (userRightsDetails.RightIdList.Select(r => new { id = r, text = r }));
            var RightNames = manager.GetAllRightsRows();
            List<Tuple<int, int, string, int>> rightsnamelist = new List<Tuple<int, int, string, int>>();
            foreach (var u in RightNames)
            {
                foreach (var i in rights)
                {
                    if (i.id == u.Id)
                    {
                        var RightsID = u.Id;
                        var ParentsID = u.ParentId;
                        var RightsNames = u.Name;
                        var RightsColor = u.TypeColor;
                        rightsnamelist.Add(new Tuple<int, int, string, int>(RightsID, ParentsID, RightsNames, RightsColor));

                    }
                }

            }

            return PartialView("_UserRightsTreeListPartial", rightsnamelist);
        }

        return View("_UserRightsTreeListPartial");
    }
```

**JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".dxgv").click(function () {
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
        var $tds = $row.find("td:nth-child(1)");
        $.each($tds, function () {
            var insertText = $(this).text();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("UserRightsTreeListPartial", "Home")',
                data: { 'userLogin': insertText },
                type: "post",
                cache: false,
                success: function(rightsnamelist) { $(UserTreePopupControl).html(rightsnamelist); }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Table Row HTML**

```
<tr id="UserGridView_DXDataRow0" class="dxgvDataRow">
        <td class="dxgvCommandColumn dxgv dx-ac"><a class="dxbButton dxgvCommandColumnItem dxgv__cci dxbButtonSys" data-args="[['CustomButton','Rights Popup',0],1]" id="UserGridView_DXCBtn0" href="javascript:;" style="font-size: 0pt;"><img title="Rights Popup" class="dx-vam" src="/images/icon_popup.png" alt="Rights Popup" id="UserGridView_DXCBtn0Img"></a></td>
        <td class="dxgv" style="border-right-width:0px;">//USERNAME</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: _THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS_? What error?

Comment: Problem probably would have been a better word, my mistake, the problem is that the popup control isn't updating so it is just showing blank. @StephenMuecke

Comment: Your making an ajax call but you don't do anything with the partial view it returns. Assuming you controller method is correctly returning the html, to need to update the DOM in the success call back - `success: function(data) { $(someElement).html(data); }`

Comment: I have tried this but it refreshes the whole page, do i need to add an Ajax form somewhere? @StephenMuecke

Comment: No, you already have an ajax function. Not sure what you mean by _refreshes the whole page_? What is `$(UserTreePopupControl)`? - your function is replacing that element with the partial you returned (and its doing it in a loop so that does not make much sense - you just keep replacing what you just added). And what is the element with `class="dxgv"`?

Comment: dxgv is the class that devexpress gives to its table rows. I have debugged and the controller is sending and receiving the correct data. The whole page updates when I click on a table row, rather than just the `UserTreePopupControl`, I tried `"#UserTreePopupControl"` but this didn't do anything @StephenMuecke

Comment: But having an `$.each()` does not make sense (and it looks like its only one element anyway). If the whole page is updating, then I assume the plugin is doing that. Try adding `return false;` as the last line in the `$(".dxgv").click(function () {` function so it cancels any other action being performed by the plugin.

Comment: And if `class="dxgv"` is the class name added to the `<tr>` element, then `var $row = $(this).closest("tr");` does not make any sense either. I suggest you show the html of a typical row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86671/discussion-between-hjardine-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined a variable named `UserTreePopupControl` so your success callback - `$(UserTreePopupControl).html(..)` - is not updating the correct element. In addition, your script is unnecessarily finding the elements parent `<tr>` element and then finding its second `<td>` element, which is actually the element you clicked on (i.e. `$(this)`), and since its a single element, there is no need for an `$.each()` loop.

From the discussion in chat, the element you want to update has `id="UserRightsTreeList_D"` so the correct script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".dxgv").click(function () {
    var insertText = $(this).text();
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("UserRightsTreeListPartial", "Home")',
      data: { 'userLogin': insertText },
      type: "post",
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#UserRightsTreeList_D').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```